# Is there resize event listener in fxml?

Tags: javascript, java, javafx-8, fxml

I want to set the width property of a node whenever the height property is changed or vice versa to make the width and height property be always equal. I know I can do this easily by this code-

```
region.heightProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observable, Number oldValue, Number newValue) {
        region.setPrefWidth(region.getHeight());
    }
});
```

But I want to do it in javascript without any need of extra .java file, like this-

```
<Region prefWidth="48" onResizeEvent="#onResizeEvent" >             
    <fx:script>
        function onResizeEvent() {
            setWidth(getHeight());
        }
    </fx:script>
</Region>
```

I could not find any way to listen to height changed or size changed event in fxml after a lot of searching.

Comment: No-one uses `<fx:script>` in real life. Define a controller for this.

Comment: I am using the scene builder. It does not support user controls quite so well. if I do write a controller for this, I can not edit it under scene builder. that's why I am trying to put everything in fxml.

Comment: You can still use SceneBuilder for the FXML, and use your favorite IDE for your Java code. You will not be able to write an entire JavaFX application with no Java code at all, so you may as well set it up the correct way at the outset.

Comment: I am trying to do something like that now. I am trying to create a user control which can be visible in scene builder too.

Comment: See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#custom_components for (one approach to) creating custom controls.